# refresh the circle on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm implementing an application in which I have to show google map with circle at the center of the map. I'm able draw a circle on map but after few seconds I've to update the circle's radius. I want to use same instance of map rather than creating new one. 
When i create the new circle its overlapping on older circle. I want to remove previously added circle and show new one. 
While checking the api I got this method from Circle class which will hide the circle.
myCity.setOptions({visible:false});

but the problem is I don't have access to older circle instance. 
Is there any way which will allow me to get maps markers and infoboxes assigned to that map and remove them?
Below is method which will get called interval of few seconds

```
function mapByCoordinates()
{
var lat=document.getElementById("latValue").value;
var lng=document.getElementById("lngValue").value;
var accuracy = document.getElementById("zoomValue").value;
var zoomVal=getZoomBasedOnAccuracy(accuracy);
var zm = parseInt(zoomVal);
var tempRadius = getRadiusBasedOnAccuracy(accuracy);
var amstr = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

var mapProp = {
  center:amstr,
  zoom:zm,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };  

  map.setOptions(mapProp); 


  myCity.setOptions({visible:false}); 
  infobox.close();
  myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
  center:amstr,
  radius:tempRadius  

  }); 

  marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:amstr,
  }); 
myCity.setMap(map);
myCity1.setMap(map1);

infobox = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content:"Welcome to google map",
              disableAutoPan:true
});
infobox.open(map,marker);


map.panTo(amstr);
map.setZoom(19);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Would help us to see what code you've tried so far

Comment: method added, have done some changes in it. Every time i'm creating instances at the same time I dont want to make var public. Is there any way that i can access circle info infobox assiged to the Map

Comment: It looks like the code you posted recreates the map every time it runs. If you don't want that to happen, the first thing you should do is remove that code from the routine that gets periodically executed.  What problems are you having with the posted code?

Comment: I want to remove the previously added circle and infobax from current instance of map

Comment: Is there any way by which we can remove previously added circle and infobox instances from the map object

Answer (score 5):

We can make the already drawn circle invisible on google maps by using following method
circle.setOptions({visible:false}); 
and can null the instance of that map.

Comment: but how to refresh

Comment: @EdathadanChiefakaArun: setRadius() takes effect straight away, doesn't setOptions()?

Answer (score 2):

Try `circle.setRadius(radiusvalue)`

Comment: helpful and effective